# Slurm QoS limits with specific EC2 node types in AWS ParallelCluster setup

Tags: slurm

We run Slurm on a AWS ParallelCluster and have several partitions defined with various EC2 types.

In an effort to protect against cost runaway I have been given a task to figure out some QoS limits on our setup.

As cost is dictated in "discrete intervals" by the number and type of EC2 instances, they seems like the most obvious thing to limit.

I have tried to figure out a way to define these limits based on the EC2 type defined by ParallelCluster, e.g. a user with a given QOS can only spin up a number of instances of a specific type, but so far have not been able to identify a way to do this.

Is this even possible in Slurm or can it only be done on TRES like cores, memory, GPUs etc?